# msal 1.2.0 loginSilent()

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm currently facing an issue that I have to login with msal without any redirections and stumbled across the [release notes](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/releases/tag/v1.2.0) of msal 1.2.0 where it said that there is now the feature "silentLogin()" included.
After installing msal 1.2.0 (via npm install) the function silentLogin() isn't there...

I just replaced the `msalInstance.liginRedirect(request);` with `msalInstance.loginSilent(request);`

Does anyone know more about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a mistake in the release notes, and should not have been included. We'll make sure this gets fixed. Apologies for the confusion!

(We are planning to add an `ssoSilent` API in a future version of the library, but that is not available yet.)